# Is increasing the class weight of minority class in Random Forest algorithm decreasing the performance?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, overfitting

I am trying to classify an imbalanced dataset (census dataset with approx. 3:1 imbalance) using Random Forest algorithm in python, and what I observed that increasing the  class weight of the minority class further increases the misclassification of minority class data(as seen from confusion matrix). What is more surprising that upon increasing the class weight of the **majority class** instead, the results are better (misclassification of the minority class is less).

Can it be due to overfitting?

Comment: Do you have the results for the train data or OOB data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are overfitting when increasing the weight of the minority class. Maybe you should try tuning the parameters using cross-validation. Additionally it could help to consider both, the changes in the training and the validation error to identify overfitting.